# RStudio states file does not exist

Tags: r, rstudio

Attempting to use the `mread` function to open a cpp file through R. However,  when I run the script I get the following:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Gustavo/Documents/R/page-2018-mrgsolve-master/model")
getwd()
#> [1] "C:/Users/Gustavo/Documents/R/page-2018-mrgsolve-master/model"

library(mrgsolve)
mod <- mread("simple", "model")
#> Error: project directory 'model' must exist and be readable.
```

Obviously I am setting the directory to "model" itself. So why isn't R able to read it? Any help would be appreciated as I am still learning R and want to learn the mrgsolve package as well.

Additional info: R version 3.4.4. Rtools version 3.4.0. Rstudio version 1.1.463.

Comment: Why do you have model twice in the path?

Comment: `mod <- mread("simple", "../model")`?

Comment: @Elin: I'm not sure I understand your comment? The first two functions just show that the work directory is in model.

Comment: @DouglasMesquita So I tried using the wd itself as the command, but then I end up with the following. I believe this might be the result of R wanting me to place Rtools in the front of the path, right?
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/Users/Gustavo/DOCUME~1/R/R-34~1.4/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/Gustavo/DOCUME~1/R/R-34~1.4/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="simple-mread-source.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="simple-mread-source.o"' had status 127

Comment: My comment is the same as @DouglasMesquita's.  Did you try what he said?  In your code in the question you are pointing at a "C:/Users/Gustavo/Documents/R/page-2018-mrgsolve-master/model/model"

Comment: @Elin, I did but it did not work either.

Comment: Try taking the model segment out of the wd.

Comment: @Elin Unfortunately, it did not work either but I did find a solution. Posting that solution in another comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An adaptation to the email I sent my colleagues that were assisting me with a similar issue:

To review, I was unable to open any files through RStudio because RStudio returned error messages indicating either that the file itself or the work directory did not exist. I've done multiple installations of different versions of R, RStudio, and Rtools in an attempt to resolve the issue. I also moved the locations of files and programs of interest and changed the work directory to see if that made a difference. Unfortunately, when RStudio is first initiated on a computer, it establishes a "hidden directory" folder that retains the settings of the program when it was first initiated. However, by deleting this folder, RStudio was wiped and I was able to regain control of where files would be stored and read as desired (more on this in the following link: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State). A combination of this and forcing Rtools to the front of the 'path' also allowed me to resolve 'status 127' errors that I was receiving as well.

Unfortunately, this is the result of a more personal issue between the initial settings that RStudio took to my computer and my attempt to manipulate where RStudio should read files which I guess were discordant of one another? Regardless, it seems that I would need to be more cognizant of how RStudio establishes a folder which retains its initial settings.

Comment: Oh ... so here is my advice.  First, when using R studio it is helpful to use the "project" feature.  This will set a folder for your project and  automatically use that location as the base path.  Second a trick is to use the file window and find the file you want and click on it. The load function will then show you the path name in the console.